# Cannot disable the WinHttpAutoProxySvc service

Tags: windows-10, dhcp, windows-services

For something I am working on, I need to be able to stop and start the `Dhcp Client` service. However, when I attempt to do so through elevated command prompt I am greeted with `System error 5 has occurred` and `Access is denied`. I believe the error is caused when Windows tries to stop the `WinHttpAutoProxySvc` since that is one of its dependencies. To my knowledge, this is seemed to be a problem while back in 2018 so I am wondering if this is still not fixed. Discussion: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-build-1803winhttp-web-proxy-cant-be/74673a26-fd69-4d83-9ab8-5cb616b4dde5. Please correct me and let me know if this is intentional and not an error that needs to be fixed. If so, what am I missing in order to disable the `Dhcp Client` service?

```
Stopping the DHCP Client service will also stop these services.

   IP Helper
   WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service
   Network Connected Devices Auto-Setup
   Network List Service
   Network Location Awareness

Do you want to continue this operation? (Y/N) [N]: y
The IP Helper service is stopping.
The IP Helper service was stopped successfully.

System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the following with Windows 11, but it should work with Windows 10 as well.

You can disable WinHttp Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service by editing a registry setting, i.e. using regedit (Registry Editor) with admin privileges. Make sure to back up before making any changes! The registry setting you want is under:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinHttpAutoProxySvc
```

It's a DWORD value titled `Start`. Double-click to edit this key, and set its value to `4`. Click OK to save your changes. Then restart Windows.

`WinHttp Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service` should now be disabled, and as a result, it should no longer start or run. Without it, you should be able to stop and restart DHCP Client freely.

One consideration: Note that a couple of other services depend on this one, so they probably won't work any longer, either: `NcaSvc` ("Network Connectivity Assistant") and `iphlpsvc` ("IP Helper"). I don't think either of these services are absolutely essential, but your mileage may vary, of course. Follow these steps at your own risk.

Thanks to https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-disable-web-proxy-auto-discovery-wpad-in-windows , item 4, for the registry key information. Let me know how it goes. (If this information is even still relevant to you, that is! 3 years later, heh.)